# How to use JavaScript paste event to allow numbers in Struts 2

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have a textfield which should allow pasting only numbers in Struts 2.

I tried using `onPaste` attribute in textfield but it throws below exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
 /WEB-INF/**.jsp Attribute onPaste invalid for tag textfield according to TLD
```

Is there anyway to do above function without paste event?

Comment: code goes something like this <s:textfield onpaste="return isAllowNu()" />       struts version is 2.09

Comment: Looks like it was clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic attributes not allowed in Struts 2.0. You should upgrade to the latest version. Currently [2.3.20](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts2320) is available.

> Struts 2.3.20 is the "best available" version of Struts in the 2.3 series.

`onpaste` is a HTML attribute to dynamically bind the event handler to the element. But you can also use a jQuery code to do it manually

```
$("input[type=text]").on("paste", function() {
  return isAllowNu();
});
```

It will handle `paste` event for all `input` text elements. The `texfield`s are generating these HTML tags.