# How do I get id of Dynamic radio buttons using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I am getting the name dynamically. How do I get this alert on the screen when someone clicks on the radio button

```html
<td style="padding-left: 5px;">
  <s:radio name="answer_%{#questionId}" list="@com.jiem.sims.util.CommonUtil@buildOptionMap(#viewInfo.mstSurveyQuestion.choiceDisplayTextValue)" value="%{#session.dbAnswerMap.get(#questionId)}" cssClass="radio-inline" theme="questionnaireTheme"></s:radio>
</td>
```

```js
$("input:radio[name^='answer_']").click(function() {
  alert("working bro  ........");
});
```

Comment: Your radio buttons appear to have no `id` attribute. Do you mean that you want to get their `name` instead? If so, `this.name` in the event handler will do it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Can you please provide a simple example?

Comment: `alert(this.name)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan alert is not getting called

Comment: In that case please add your actual HTML output to the question, not the JSP. This way we can create a working example of the issue. Also check your console for errors

Comment: Making assumptions about the above, the code I suggested works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/j1ft2mxw/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i am getting this type of html in browser
 <input type="radio" name="answer_4002" id="surveyAnswer_answer_40024" checked="checked" value="4" class="radio-inline">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227195/discussion-between-swapnil-kadam-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: Thanks for confirming, however the code still works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/brpvq74y/. If you're having issues there must be a configuration issue on your end. This is why I suggested checking the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan console is clear.Not getting any error

Comment: Why do you use jQuery for event handler? It is very simple to know that Struts2 tags support dynamic attributes. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27401751/573032) answer because you didn't provide a version of Struts.